# Loop through a Javascript Object values when its key matches specific string

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have a function that loops through an Object's keys until the key matches a keyword within the input. After finding a match, how can I then loop through the matched Object keys values ?

```js
let obj = {
  music: {
    "do you like music": "Yes I do",
    "what music do you like": "Jazz"
  },

  sports: {
    "Do you like sports": "Yes"
  }
};

let input = "i like music";

function run(input) {
  let newStr = input.split(' ');
  let key = Object.keys(obj);
  key.forEach((key) => {
    newStr.forEach((str) => {
      if (key === str) {
        console.log(key)
      }
    });
  });
};

run(input);
```

Comment: For future reference, that's what the "tidy" button on the Stack Snippet modal is for :)

Comment: what results do you expect?

Comment: Seems like arrays would make more sense for nested objects rather than using unique object keys

Comment: Why not `if(str in obj)` and then just log the str since it is the same as the key, no loops needed.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the tip (: Also I used str in obj and it achieved what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.flatMap` and return matching word `value` from `obj`

I assumed you would want to return entire `value` for matching `key`

```js
let obj = {
   music:{
     "do you like music":"Yes I do",
      "what music do you like": "Jazz"
    },
    
    sports:{
     "Do you like sports": "Yes"
    }
};

function run(i) {
  return i.split(' ').flatMap(d => obj[d] || [])[0]
}

console.log(run("i like music"))

console.log(run("i like sports"))
```

Comment: Should also note that `flatMap` does not have broad browser support and would require polyfill

Comment: @charlietfl  That’s correct. If you don’t mind me asking one thing.. i am developing myself technically and learning from you all by viewing your answers.. and understanding those. flatMap is also one of those features i learnt from SO but when i dont use it I get comment that i should use that and when I use it I get comment its not much supported.. pls can you advice if I should use it or dont prefer it Or shall always mention that it needs polyfill?.  Thank you.

Comment: MDN docs mark occasional methods as "Experimental Technology" and flatMap is one of them https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap. They also show browser support tables for most methods. Can see for example IE has no support. I'm assuming that OP is entry level developer and thus I made the comment about ployfill

Comment: It does get tricky these days though so i understand the confusion. If developing only in node and not front end feature support isn't as much of an issue. ES6 features for front end where not using transpiler or for methods that aren't supported in legacy browsers does get complicated

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much @charlietfl From now on I will also mention that it needs polyfill for Edge support. 

Comment: Why do you need `flatMap` for this? Just `map` should work because `obj[d]` isn't an array.

Comment: @slider here `flatMap` role is to get rid of all empty arrays as well, which `map` won't do by it's own. You can try changing it to `map` and you will see the difference.

Comment: Yes, but you can simply add a `filter` before `map` to only consider keys that are in `obj` and that should solve the problem. The real purpose of `flatMap` is to flatter a 2d array after `map` is applied but in this case you don't have a 2d array at all.

Comment: @slider pupose of flatmap is to flat multi dimesnsion array AND remove empty arrays... and thats what I am using it for.. also i do see filters can be introduced but why bring that in when flatmap does both for you... 

Comment: "*AND remove empty arrays*" Where did you get that?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help and tips. Never heard of flatMap before today. I'm developing in Node, so flat map wouldn't be a problem right? I'm really only making a console application

Comment: I believe if you use node version > 8 then it won't be any problem to you. @JimCiaston